# A dataset to detect multicollinearity

Tags: dataset

I want to try different collinearity tests and get feature importance in the presence of multicollinearity.

However, I don't seem to find a dataset for this. I'm particularly looking for mixture of categorical and numerical variables as my predictors and a binary variable as my response.

Any data with some explanation of the variables would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the data set CIC-IDS 2017, it has continuous as well as categorical variables and the variables have very high multicollinearity.

You can freely access the files of the data set, scroll down this page: https://www.unb.ca/cic/datasets/ids-2017.html